How does eliminativism respond to phenomenology?
How do eliminativists deal with things like desires, perceptions, pains, etc., in relation to the appearances themselves? By saying that the appearance of x is reduced to y, are they not somehow conceding the validity of phenomenology's starting point and therefore being phenomenologists themselves?
Doesn’t eliminativism at least imply an agreement on the phenomenon to be eliminated?
In other words, does the eliminativist not even concede that it can be 'fixed,' even consensually, what that phenomenon is? I don't see how this is possible. If one wants to eliminate the phenomenon of pain, it must be presupposed at the starting point.
Thank you in advance.

Phenomenology focuses on the description of experiences while eliminativism is concerned with the underlying ontology and reality of those experiences. Eliminativists would argue that what is "appearing" or being reported in first-person experience (such as pain or desire) does not have a corresponding reality beyond certain neurological or physical processes. Therefore eliminativists need to acknowledge the phenomenon as a conceptual starting point, but only to eliminate it or show it as a misrepresentation later...

@DoubleKnot So they have to assume what appears.

Indeed, to speak of the false is to reveal the true...

"Eliminativism" is eliminativism about something, do you mean eliminative materialism, i.e. eliminativism about the mental of folk psychology? That some discourse is taken as the starting point does not preclude elimination of its posits in the fundamental theory, one simply provides a redescription and offers reasons (pragmatic, psychological, etc.) for widespread misconceptions.

I can't figure out from the question what variety of eliminativism you are talking about.
