Talking about objects in mereological nihilism: correct but untrue?
Accodrding to T. Sider (p. 248–253)*, a distinction between truth and correctness is possible, such that for the mereological nihilist, statements about wholes can be untrue yet correct: ‘Correct utterances, even if untrue, play a role in communication and thought that is similar to the role played by true ones’ (p. 249). Therefore, saying that 'there is an apple on the table' is untrue but correct.
My question is: (i) can mereological nihilists claim this or is it incoherent? (ii) Can mereological nihilism assimilate a standard mereology of wholes and parts for this purpose?
*Sider, Theodore, 'Against Parthood', in Karen Bennett, and Dean W. Zimmerman (eds), Oxford Studies in Metaphysics, Volume 8, Oxford Studies in Metaphysics (Oxford, 2013; online edn, Oxford Academic, 23 Jan. 2014), https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199682904.003.0006, accessed 17 Oct. 2024.

I ask if mereological nihilism can encompass a standard mereology of wholes and parts as 'correct' but 'untrue.' My question is simple. @shindemo

And my question seeks to know developments either in favor of or against this. Do you have any? @shindemo

@shindemo In fact, what I want to know is broader. I want to know if it is also possible to introduce a standard mereology of wholes and parts

@shindemo That is an interesting derivative question. It may not be necessary, but it is possible.

(i) is the standard anti-realism/fictionalism strategy, it is not particularly controversial. In (ii), it is unclear what "standard mereology" means. Nihilism is motivated by dissolving some thorny issues concerning parts, like the composition principles, so the as-if talk would be pointless if it reproduced all of that.

@Conifold Thank you. Doesn't the nihilist still have to deal with the appearance of tables, apples, etc.? In dealing with these things, don't they assume an apparent discourse of wholes and parts?

If by "standard mereology" you just mean ordinary first order talk (formalized as "core mereology" in SEP's terminology) then that can be easily covered as "correct" using sets of simples, as van Inwagen does for example.

@Conifold Perfectly clear. Do you happen to have the Inwagen reference?

The difference here could be said to be akin to the eliminativists' claimed correct but untrue utterances from the phenomenologists...

Please elaborate further. As you know, I asked a question related to what you comment on: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/117994/how-does-eliminativism-respond-to-phenomenology @DoubleKnot

@Ian my elaboration was trying to remind you about the link from this question to that, which has just been accomplished...
